# BottomSheetDialogFragment disable animation when returning from background

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Got a class that extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

When I set the dialog to show, the slide from bottom animation occurs and the dialog is shown. Now, If I set the app to background and then bring it back to the foreground, the dialog that was already showing does the same slide in animation.

How can I disable this, that is, if the dialog is already showing, sending the app to background and then foreground does not start the animation?

Showing the dialog like this:

```
dialog = MyDialogFragment()
dialog?.run {
    val args = Bundle()
    ....
    arguments = args
    show(this@MyFragment.fragmentManager, tag)
}
```

Where the dialog class only has this:

```
class MyDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    var listener: Listener? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // inflate view
        // Given the arguments, sets up the ui

        return view
    }

    interface Listener {
        ...
    }
}
```

And that's all the code that I have for the dialog.

Comment: where do you call this method  show(this@MyFragment.fragmentManager, tag)

Comment: In `MyFragment`

Comment: Is it on any lifecycle aware method, while coming from background @Favolas

Comment: The method that shows the dialog is called from a `LiveData` observable but I have a check to see if the dialog is already showing and if it is, do not show it again.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. You should probably be using childFragmentManager if you're showing it from a fragment not just fragmentManager

Answer (score 5):

Combining @nntk and @CKotlin answers made the trick for me. I manage to fix the issue with this code :

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)
}
```

Edit:
On Android < P (API 28), it makes the app not responding to touch events. So either you don't use it or you need to surround it with a check:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, have you found another solution for versions < P? I've made a SO question on it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161454/returning-to-dialogfragment-from-another-activity-reuses-my-enter-animation

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found other solution for versions < P

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I placed a bounty on it a while back, and someone found an answer that worked!

Answer (score 1):

overwrite `onStop()` method in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

such as

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDialog().show();  // important

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same issue. I haven't fully been able to solve this, but I was able to stop the slide up animation from occurring on resume by doing the following:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Disable dialog window animations for this instance
        dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)
    }
```

This doesn't stop the background fade from animating though, so the background shade shows, disappears, and then shows again.