# Returning to DialogFragment from another Activity reuses my enter animation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have an Activity (A) that creates a DialogFragment. In that DialogFragment, I have a button which creates a new Activity (B). When I finish Activity B, it displays the DialogFragment from Activity A and it reuses that custom animation I set. How do I prevent my DialogFragment from reusing that animation when returning to Activity A?

This answer works for some devices, however it freezes the entire window on some (hence the check version)

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(-1);
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64454784/11110509

This is how I am creating my custom DialogFragment enter/exit animation:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.FragmentDialogAnim;
    return dialog;
}
```

```
<style name="FragmentDialogAnim">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/loginactivity_left_to_right</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/loginactivity_right_to_left</item>
</style>
```

loginactivity_left_to_right:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

loginactivity_right_to_left:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Here's the code for creating the DialogFragment:

https://pastebin.com/k1c6nz3p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should disable the animation in **onPause()** method of your DialogFragment instead of **onStop()** method. Just remove all the lines of code you currently have in **onStop()** method and add **onPause()** with the below lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  if(getDialog()!=null)
    getDialog().getWindow().setWindowAnimations(-1);
 }
```

By doing it in onPause() method you are disable all window animations without also to freeze any touch events.

Comment: No way, there must be another solution to this! This will remove exit animation, as well.

Comment: @NixSam I know this is old, but my solution to get round this was to reapply the animation - the trick being to put this into a runnable in the post method of one of your views, so that it doesn't get called until after the layout is drawn.

Comment: @CharlieWalker good trick, I like it. It worked! Thanks! For other ones reading this, you can add 
```
    override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            view?.post {
                dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(R.style.BottomDialogSlideAnimation)
            }
         }
```
to have exit animation when user press back.

Comment: @NixSam I have facing same issue. Is there any other solution found apart from this? As I do not want to apply setWindowAnimation.

Comment: @MohitTrivedi No, Charlie's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recycling Views can always be problematic especially if you intend it to be slightly different in each scenario.

I would recommend that either you stop recycling this Dialog and instead **create a specific Dialog for each of your different cases**, or that you simply **pass a flag into your Dialog** defining what/when to use the animations.

Comment: what do you mean by recycling dialog? I have only created this dialog once in Activity A. I am returning to Activity A from Activity B.

Comment: You return to Activity A, and the Dialog is still there? Perhaps I didn't quite understand the problem.